# how to display pop up text showing address in google map of android

Tags: android, google-maps

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {

```
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        Point screenPts = new Point();
```

//            scree.openInfoWindowHtml("Hello, **World!**" );

```
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(g, screenPts);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flag);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);  

        //TextView bubble=
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check this: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

It's really good and easy to use, much faster than rolling your own. If you want to learn you can always study the source.